# Sine anno, unknown fields in bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I am writing a thesis in LaTeX and found the problem that when e.g. the date of a referenced book/paper/etc. is unknown, the Bibliography should say 'sine anno', however I could not manage that.

Small MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=ieee,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mwe.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum~\cite{mech_vibr}.

\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

where `mwe.bib` contains:

```
@book{mech_vibr,
author = {S. Rao, Singiresu},
title = "{Mechanical Vibrations}",
date = {sine anno},
edition = {Fifth},
publisher = {Prentice Hall},
isbn = {978-0-13-212819-3},
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `year` instead of `date` if the field is not in yyyy-mm-dd format. See `biblatex` manual p. 35, sec. 2.3.8.

If you are writing in English, consider using "n.d." for "no date" (this is the *Chicago Manual of Style*'s recommendation).

PS - WorldCat tells me this book was published in 2011, but perhaps you were just using it as an example.

Comment: Thank you, working great! The usage of Latin phrases is recommended by the university, so I must follow that. And thank you, but yes, it was only an example, I have the book right beside the computer :)